# Postgresql left outer join on json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a left outer join between a json_array_elements of a table column and another table?  Something like the following, but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo,
    json_array_elements (foo.bars :: json) foo_bars
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo_bars ->> 'id') :: BIGINT = bar.ID;
```

The table structure is like the following

```
FOO
 ------------------------------------------
|  ID  | NAME |            BARS            |
|------------------------------------------|
|  1   | FOO1 | [{ "id" : 1}, { "id" : 2 }]|
|------------------------------------------|
|  2   | FOO1 |             []             |
 ------------------------------------------

BAR
 -------------
|  ID  | NAME |
|-------------|
|  1   | BAR1 |
|-------------|
|  2   | BAR2 |
 -------------
```

I would expect the output of the query to be

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
|  ID  | NAME |            BARS            |  ID  | NAME |
|------------------------------------------|-------------|
|  1   | FOO1 | [{ "id" : 1}, { "id" : 2 }]|  1   | BAR1 |
|------------------------------------------|-------------|
|  1   | FOO1 | [{ "id" : 1}, { "id" : 2 }]|  2   | BAR2 |
|------------------------------------------|-------------|
|  2   | FOO1 |             []             | null | null |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "doesn't work." is not really a good description of query behaviour vs. desired behaviour.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes it is possible and your query does exactly that.
We can prove it by introducing a third row in `foo` table:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06dfe/2

Your problem is not with `LEFT JOIN` to `json_array_elements` but with implicit lateral cross join. Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo 
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements (foo.bars :: json) foo_bars 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo_bars ->> 'id') :: BIGINT = bar.ID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06dfe/5

What you want is a lateral left join between `foo` and `json_array_elements`:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    json_array_elements (foo.bars :: json) foo_bars ON true
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo_bars ->> 'id') :: BIGINT = bar.ID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06dfe/6

Comment: This works great.  Even works with null json as well.  I'd never heard of SQL Fiddle before either.  I wish I could give you 100 upvotes for that one.

Comment: I remove the LATERAL and the result is the same.

Comment: @鄭元傑 it's implicit probably, it was years ago and I don't understand it anymore.

Comment: @JakubKania I am still trying to understand  LATERAL. OTZ

Comment: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-use-lateral-joins

Comment: Updated link from @Goofyahead 's comment:
https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-use-lateral-joins-in-postgresql