# mysql JSON LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, json

```
TABLE streams;

+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | name     | stream                                                      | server      | bouquet     | 
+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | HOME     | ["http://ur11.com/", "http://ur12.com/"]                    | ["1", "3"]  | ["3","2"]   |
+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+

TABLE servers;

+----+-------------------+
| id | server            |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Main              |
|  2 | Server #1         |
|  3 | Server #2         |
|  4 | Server #3         |
|  5 | Server #4         |
+----+-------------------+
```

I need to run LEFT JOIN on table streams and to retrieve using first index in streams.server value of servers.server:

For Example i need left join to get this result:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | name     | stream                                                      | server      | bouquet     | 
+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | HOME     | ["http://ur11.com/", "http://ur12.com/"]                    | Main        | ["3","2"]   |
+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So the point is to get first index from streams.server witch is 1 and then LEFT JOIN on servers.id to get servers.server name witch is in this case Main

I installed mysql 5.7 version witch includes JSON support but i did not get clue how to use LEFT JOIN on JSON field type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select s.*, se.server
from streams s join
     servers se
     on se.id = json_extract(s.server, '$[0]');
```

Depending on the exact version of MySQL you installed, you can also use `s.server->'$[0]'`.

Comment: @John . . . You may have to fiddle with the `json_extract()`.  For instance, the double quotes suggest that the values in the json field are stored as strings, whereas the values in `servers` look like ints.

Comment: This would not work when doing the WHERE, you must cast to UNSIGNED before: SELECT..... ON table1.id = CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(table2,"$.id") AS UNSIGNED)

Answer (score 2):

I got it workijng using your above solutions:

```
select s.*, se.server
from streams s left join
servers se
on se.id = CAST(json_extract(s.server, '$[0]') AS UNSIGNED);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements (foo.bars :: json) foo_bars 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo_bars ->> 'id') :: BIGINT = bar.ID;
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628950/postgresql-left-outer-join-on-json-array)